# How do I properly encrypt a byte array using RSA encryption

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rsa

So I'm currently trying to encrypt a byte array using RSA, and the reason behind it is that I'm following the documentation over at https://github.com/vexsoftware/votifier#protocol-documentation.

It says that it needs to be encrypted before it's sent and I tried encrypting it doing it this way.

```
public static void Encryption()
{
    var publicKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>THE_KEY_HERE</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";

    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(4096))
    {
        try
        {
            // client encrypting data with public key issued by server                    
            rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey.ToString());

            var encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(packet, true);

            var base64Encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
        }
        finally
        {
            rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But this line `var encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(packet, true);` throws the exception `Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'Bad Length.'`

`packet` is a byte array that's 256 bytes in total.

How do I properly encrypt the array of bytes?

Comment: For RSA, the data size must not exceed the key size (modulus). In fact, the data must even be smaller, since part of the allowed length is reserved for padding. How long is the key (number of bits in the modulus)?

Comment: @rene I've updated the question, thanks for pointing that out, I forgot to fix that. Now it looks the way it should

@Topaco the key is 172 characters, resulting in 172 bytes. I pasted the key in here to test it `https://mothereff.in/byte-counter`

Comment: In the XML representation the modulus is specified Base64 encoded. 172 bytes correspond Base64 decoded to 128 bytes.

Comment: Also, you seem to use OAEP (with SHA1) as padding (since the 2nd parameter of `Encrypt()` is `true`), which means max. 86 bytes for the payload (see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100)).

Comment: It says that they key size is 1024 bytes, the docs says it should be 2048

Comment: The documentation and the code itself are not great, but on most platforms it's likely that the server is using RSA with PKCS1 ver 1.5 padding. To get compatible results with .Net you must set the second parameter of `rsa.Encrypt()` to `false`. The claim that the protocol is secure is just that, a claim. The code fails to fully specify the cipher transformation string, which means he is at the mercy of the platform defaults. That's a sign of java cryptography inexperience at least.